# How to find through association when the model is referenced more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

When associating a model multiple time, how do you create elegant queries for each association?

```
  Account
    has_many :things
    has_many :things, foreign_key: 'otherthing_id'
```

So, now rails gets confused using account.things.  Which one are you calling for, thing or otherthing?  Is there a way to tell the query which thing association to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different association names

```
  Account
    has_many :things
    has_many :otherthings, foreign_key: 'otherthing_id'
```

You can also pass a custom class, if it can't be inferred from the association.

```
    has_many :other_things, foreign_key: 'otherthing_id', class_name: 'Thing'
```

Here's some [basic documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Is there more to defining the other_things has_many?  How will rails create the association without knowing the associated model?  has_many :things, knows the associated model...but, has_many :other_things does not.  class_name: "Thing" perhaps.